# SharePoint 2013 Server stopped totally after modifying its custom master page accidentally

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a major issue, I was doing some modifications to our portal and accidentally I modified the custom default master page and then the portal has totally stopped giving the below error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /en/Pages/default.aspx

Please I need your help urgenlty as this is our production system and all of our work have delayed.

Regards,

Ali

Answer (score 1):

Temp fix: Apply a default master page while you get the original version of the custom one and reapply it. Also the MP Gallery should be using versioning, so you can most likely rollback the page.

If you can not set the default master page via the UI, try setting it via Powershell.

Also try accessing the /_layouts/settings.aspx for the site directly. So you might be able to work from there.

Comment: /_layouts/settings.aspx (with the underscore)

Comment: Yes I can aacess "/_layouts/settings.aspx", and also I can change the master page to the default one properly. But whe I revert back to the custom one, I got the same error.
But how can I apply versioning on the master page.

Comment: From the settings you can access the MP-gallery. There you need to locate your masterpage. Check the versioning of that file and revert it to a propper version. Unless you updated the file on your drive... (Ghosting/Unghosting is evil - avoid if possible - server side dependency)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, I had a backup from the last week. So I restored all the .master files from it, and replaced them to the current files, and the portal worked fines.

It seems that when I modified div in the master file, SPD has changed something else automatically in another file, or perhaps within the same file, not sure.

Regards,